# Nginx - How do I know when $http_referer is not set or empty?

Tags: nginx, request, http-referer

How do I know when the nginx variable $http_referer is not set or empty?

I receive some requests that don't have a http referer. In nginx logs $http_referer appears like that: "-". What I am trying to do is to "return 403;" if the $http_referer is not set or empty as in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using regular expressions but seems not to be working - or rejects everything with 403. I searched for a method that would tell me if a nginx variable is set or not.... but I didn't find it yet.

Comment: What if my browser is configured to never send referer headers for any site?

Comment: Hmm... what I really need is to deny every acces to resources of the requests that are plain GETs for example and they don't have 'anyone' sending them... such as http_referer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers

```
valid_referers server_names ~.;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    return   403;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I got an error: '[emerg]: the "none" or "blocked" referers are specified in the "valid_referers" directive without any valid referer'

Comment: @Clawsy Fixed version blocks every request with empty referer. Any non-empty referer considered correct.

Comment: `server_names ~.` works as opposed to `valid_referers none;` which throws the error @Clawsy mentions.  @Tim's working technique sets the list of valid `server_names` to match any server by setting it to a regular expression using `~` and any character using `.` .  See also : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if ($http_referer ~ /^$/) {
    return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, likes below:

```
set $flag 0;
if ($http_referer = "-") {
    set $flag 1;
}
if ($flag = 1) {
    return 403;
}
```